# Shear-Waves and Stress

Tags: seismic

-I study the near-surface via seismic reflection surveying with shear-waves. I know that effective stress strongly influences the velocity behavior of any body wave in the **near-surface** (5 - 50 m). My question is this:

*Does effective stress influence SH (horizontally-polarized) or SV (vertically-polarized) shear-waves more? If you have an answer to this, please provide a citation/reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Effective stress is often anisotropic, so it would affect SV and SH differently. In some cases, the orientation of the horizontal component of the effective stress can change due to the processes that formed the sediments. I haven't studied it in connection with shear wave seismics, so I have no good reference. The tricky part is often to separate P and SH energy, somehow it can be managed by stacking phase reversed shots. Maybe something similar can be applied on SV/SH arrivals?